# Passing a VARIANT by ref to a COM object

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get data from COM object. But I don't know how to passing object variant by ref (Object)variant. Please help me.

```
    int physicalMember = 4;//try to get data for member ID=4
    int[] memberList;//store list of analytical members belong the physicalMember (equal 4 in this case)
    //Get number of member for specific physical member. nPhyMembNo type int
    int nAnaMember = nAnaMember = osGeom.GetAnalyticalMemberCountForPhysicalMember(physicalMember);
    //Get Analytical Members For Physical Member
    memberList = new int[nAnaMember];
    //dynamic IOSGeometryUI.GetAnalyticalMembersForPhysicalMember(object nPhyMembNo, object nAnalyticalMember, ref object MemberList)
    osGeom.GetAnalyticalMembersForPhysicalMember(physicalMember, nAnaMember, ref memberList);
```

combine error: cannot convert from 'ref int[]' to 'ref object. I'm try to create object memberList=null but no data get back.

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MydVh.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the [`ref` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) it passes the object as a reference instead of the value.

[A `ref` object cannot be used as a parameter *implicitly*.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference-an-example) You must cast the object to the desired type **explicitly** before using it as a reference.

For Example:

```cs
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

object explicitlyCastedObject = numbers ;

YourComMethod(ref explicitlyCastedObject);

public static void YourComMethod(ref object obj)
{
}
```

This also will only work if the COM method on the other end of the call knows what to do with your object, aka. understanding it should be used as a `int[]`(in my example above).

Comment: Thanks DekuDesu, It really helpful and It work fine.

Comment: It's not working if ref object return VARIANAT array. void GetSelectedBeams(ref object naBeamNos, object nIsSorted); -> //Returned selected member number ID(s) VARIANAT array. It is not working because ref object naBeamNos return VARIANAT array . Sorry because I am an engineer so my programming skills are not good.

Comment: You you still receiving the same error, or are you getting an unexpected result after the error was resolved?

Comment: Please see my edit post. I've post the image show my problem.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand, Unfortunately you'll have to ask a new question with the updated information since this no longer involves the original question. This is so others more well informed than I can see the new question and help out.

Comment: Thank you. Please help me for the new question.